# В Android Studio перестали работать подсказки (suggestions)

Tags: android-studio

При редактировании файлов xml, до обновления, работали подсказки по <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Space</kbd>, а теперь всплывает сообщение "No suggestions".

Или, удерживая <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+` клик по названию строкового ресурса "s_time" (`android:text="@string/s_time"`), раньше происходил переход в файл ресурса, а теперь всплывает сообщение "Cannot find declaration to go to", хотя строка в ресурсе есть.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Закройте Android Studio. Удалите в корне проекта папку `.idea`. Запустите Android Studio и откройте проект заново.

Comment: Не помогло. Даже комп перезагружал после этого.

Comment: А вы точно линтер не отключали?

Comment: `File` -> `Settings`. *Project Settings*: `Inspections` -> `Android Lint` должно быть включено. В *IDE Settings*: `Editor` -> `Code Completion` -> должно быть включено `Autopopup code completion`.

Comment: все сделал, проверил, перезагрузил, ничего не поменялось. При редактировании xml пишу android: нажимаю Ctrl+Space и появляется опять "No suggestions"

Comment: Power Save Mode не включен?

Comment: выключил и в настройках выключил, перезагрузил студию и не помогло. Проблемы начались после обновления студии.

Comment: @Suvitruf, может поможет переустановка студии? это на мой взгляд самый простой способ если ничего уже не помогает :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko лучше, всё же, попытаться найти причину.

Comment: @Suvitruf, это я так на крайний случай :) вообще я читал что нужно удалить папки `.idea` должно помочь, как вы и говорили, но похоже что не помогло :( хотя это довольно странно

Comment: да, странно, что удаление не помогло. А переустанавливать студию очень не хочется. попробую еще раз удалить папку .idea